# SFP to RJ45 for 10Gbit network

Tags: ethernet, layer1, sfp, 10gbase, transceiver

I am in the process of upgrading some of our network into 10Gb and grabbed the following:

A network switch by netgear, mode:GS110EMX

A bunch of assorted cat8 cables(for future proofing)

Two 10gtek 10gb PCI network cards(model: BCM57810S) - the underlining issue.

So upon recieving all these items. i forgot to check what connection the PCI network card has and upon expecting the device, it used SFP type connection.

I did not know such a connection type existed and thought all network based connections are via RJ45. I have now read about it and aware of it now but my question is below:

Is there a adapter that i can use to connect my cat 8 cable between the SFP NIC device and to my new switch?

Is there any implications in doing so? Loss of speed? reliability of connection?

If there is no adapter or the adapter loses speed and reliability, i may return the NIC and try and find a RJ45 varient of it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify the locations of the devices.  Same room with direct patch cord between them?  Or switch in network closet and PCI network cards on desk and attempt to use the buildings structured cabling?  If attempting to use the building cabling, any idea what cat rating it is?

Comment: Sticking with TP for >10G is just expensive, especially to SFP+, and rather pointless. Go DAC or fiber.

Comment: The location of the devices are about 2m away or less from eachother. the two devices are a desktop workstation and a tower Server. The switch will along with the NIC will give the ability to transfer up to 10gbits between the two devices

Comment: In that case Ron’s suggestion of getting copper SFP+ works. Return those cat8 patch cords and get some cheaper cat6a ones.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

First a 10 Gbps network adapters use SFP+, not SFP.

Next, you can get a 10GBase-T SFP+ module for your adapter, rather than one of the fiber variants. In most cases, 10 Gbps adapters will have SPF+ slots so that you can choose which type of cabling you are using and get the correct SFP+ module.

---

You also need to understand Category-8 cabling, which is shielded cabling, was adopted for 25GBase-T and 40GBaset-T, up to 24 meters horizontal, and 30 meter channel length, much shorter than the other categories. That means that a stranded patch cord on each end can be no more that three meters, and the solid-core horizontal cable can be no more than 24 meters. That severely limits it over Category-6a cabling that also supports 10GBase-T, where you have up to 90 meters of solid-core horizontal cable, and up to five meters of stranded patch cord on each end (100 meter channel length). Also, [shielded cabling must maintain a continuous shield from end-to-end, cannot be mixed with UTP or unshielded components (connectors), and it must be properly grounded, at least, at each end (probably at each termination point, too)](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/39070/8499).

In either case (Category-6a or Category-8), you will need to have the cable installation done by an experienced professional with the proper (proper means very expensive) test equipment, not the cheap wiremap tool you would normally buy to test phone cabling, because [modern networking needs a lot more than simple electrical connectivity](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/42697/8499). The installer will run each cable through a full test suite, correct any problems, and give you a report for each.

Comment: Reading between the lines, it sounds like the distance between his devices is short, and he’s purchased preterminated patchcords (as opposed to attempting a structured cabling installation). So your advice to get professional installers to install the structured cabling may not apply. But concur with your 10GBase-T SFP+ and cat6a recommendations assuming distance is within spec.

Comment: Well, if the switch is in the data closet, then the horizontal cabling will not match the patch cords, and it will not work, anyway. Three meters may work for patch cords, but if they are longer than that, there could be trouble. Category-8 cabling is very different than the normal UTP cabling, and it doesn't mix with any installed UTP.

Comment: the distance in question is no more than 2m at present. It would go to about 10-20m in the future when i move locations but for now its just 2m cabling i am using as the switch and the devices sit very close to eachother

Comment: For 10 to 20 meters, you cannot use the stranded patch cables with Category-8. It seems strange that you do not have a data closet for your switch where you can connect multiple users. It would be awkward (both in proximity and in the logistics of the cables) to have the switch in the open where all the users simply run a cable over to it. Your company should spend the money to do it correctly because its business depends on the network, and it could lose a lot of money if the network is down for any period of time (someone spilling coffee in a switch).